# How to zoomin zoomout UIimageView with slider value change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uislider, pinchzoom

I have a Image View

I Can zoom in and zoom out Image with two fingers using following code

```
{
[super viewDidload]
 imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 ,420)];      
      [imageScrollView addSubview:imgView];

      // imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.75;
      imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;

      imageScrollView.zoomScale = 0.29;
      imageScrollView.delegate=self;
      [self.view addSubview:imageScrollView];
}


 //UIScrollViewDelegate methods for Zoom

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
      return imgView;
}



- (CGRect)zoomRectForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)ImgscrollView withScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center 
{
      CGRect zoomRect;
      zoomRect.size.height = ImgscrollView.frame.size.height / scale;
      zoomRect.size.width  = ImgscrollView.frame.size.width  / scale;
      // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
      zoomRect.origin.x = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
      zoomRect.origin.y = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);
      return zoomRect;
}
```

But my requirement is to **increase or decrease zoom levels with slide values instead of two fingers zoom.**

```
 - (IBAction) sliderValueChange:(UISlider *)sender
 {
     //--- ???????
  }
```

[image]

By changing slider value to increase the zoom level of image increase and same in decrease zoom level by decreasing slider values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by using

```
[imageScrollView setZoomScale:sender.value];
```

to update the zoom when the slider is changed.